# Silver bars above and below Bootstrap 3 navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

There are thin silver or white maybe, bars at the top and bottom of my Bootstrap 3 navbar. I'm unable to locate the CSS class to change. I tried using Chrome console to work it out but I'm having no luck on this one. Can someone lend their expertise?

[image]

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/locohost/po2wuLmz/)

`Some "code" needed here or you can't post a JSFiddle link?`

Comment: It's helpful to have code and a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Mmmm, what code? Do you mean paste my stylesheet?

Comment: Put the stylesheet and html in the fiddle

Comment: just replace border-color: #E7E7E7; by border-color: none;

Comment: @Fabio border-color in what CSS class name?

Comment: @JoseMagana Fiddle is up and working. Added link to OP.

Comment: @Fabio Oh Ok I see what you mean. Just tried in the JSFiddle, it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your boostrap.min.css file look for:

```
.navbar{position:relative;min-height:50px;margin-bottom:20px;border:1px solid transparent}
```

Change this to:

```
.navbar{position:relative;min-height:50px;margin-bottom:20px;border:none}
```

Comment: Hey John, I figured it out a few mins ago. I updated the fiddle. Your answer actually includes the border fix so I'm accepting it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.navbar .navbar-default {
        background-color: #1D0657;
        border-color: none;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t71pn9k6/)

Comment: I looked at the fiddle link you provided. Still see the long horizontal silver bars above/below the navbar.

Answer (score 0):

There is `background-color` and `border-color` on `.navbar-default` from **bootstrap CSS** file.

You need to set them to `transparent`.

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aniskhan001/po2wuLmz/4/)**